# Facebook: How to hide 'Work and Education' from specific people?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

In Facebook how to hide my "Work and Education" or "About You" details from specific people? Is there a way to hide from specific people?

Answer (score 1):

If you want hide any section from your few friends from your timeline, just set audience as `Custom`.

- Go to your timeline.
- Click on About.
- Click on the section you want to edit from left hand side and select the subsection from right hand side, click on pencil symbol to edit.
- Now select audience as `Custom` and then `Specific People or Lists..`.
- You will see `Don't share this with These people or lists` option, write your friend's names (or lists) with whom you don't want share information about you.